# Need all rights to my MySQL user

Tags: mysql, permissions

I was trying to create a new db when suddenly it said I don't have rights. The user I am logged in is `root` . I tried giving all the privileges with `grant all` Permission but my user doesn't have rights to execute it. I even tried `select * from MySQL.user` And as I expected I don't have rights. This is my local test system where I had done the setup and I remember that I have not created any other user. I am totally lost and have no idea where to look. Need help !

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS` while logged in as that user.

Comment: You obviously aren't using root. Or I should say the admin user**

Comment: Output - GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost'

Comment: @FirebladeDan yes, I think so too.

Comment: @FirebladeDan I used username 'admin', but the same issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option.
Connect to the mysqld server with just: mysql (i.e. no -p option, and username may not be required).
Issue the following commands in the mysql client:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that, you should be able to run GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost'; and have it work.

or

Stop MySQL service
Run `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` &
Type mysql -u root -p and press enter.
Enter your password
At the mysql command line enter:

```
use mysql;
```

Then execute this query:

```
insert into `user` (`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`, `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`, `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`, `max_user_connections`) 
values('localhost','admin','','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','','0','0','0','0');
```

Comment: Access denied : you need (at least one of) the reload privilege for this operation

Comment: are you trying with root as user? login as root Bhavik

Comment: That's what I'm not sure as of this point, when I had done the setup I didn't create any user, I was able to log in with the user 'root' and 'admin' without any pwd